# Plot pie chart with values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My df is below

```
sales_qtr_month = sales_qtr.groupby(['Month']).agg('sum')
```

```
    Sales2015   Sales2016
Month       
Q1  5.485800e+06    6.997953e+06
Q2  5.390862e+06    7.237361e+06
Q3  6.164094e+06    7.861546e+06
Q4  5.713634e+06    7.567868e+06
```

pie chart code

```
sales_qtr_month.plot.pie(figsize=(15,15),subplots=True)
```

[image]

- How to add the values of Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 to chart?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to generate your data, so I will just generate something similar to cover all the steps.

```
# Make some data
raw_data = {'Sales2016': [10, 20, 900, 100, 50],
            'Sales2015': [10, 20, 30, 100, 50],
        'Month': ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5']}

# Generate a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Sales2016','Sales2015', 'Month'])
```

After this, I will run groupby() which won't change the data at all. The purpose of this groupby() is to get the DataFrameGroupBy which is similar to the one given by OP.

```
df_sum = df.groupby(['Month']).agg('sum')
```

Which constructs

```
    Sales2016   Sales2015
Month       
Q1      10         10
Q2      20         20
Q3      900        30
Q4      100        100
Q5      50         50
```

From this point, I would flatten the DataFrameGroupBy and index it with month.

```
df_flatten = df_sum.reset_index().set_index('Month')
```

The [link](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html) provided by [steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9900084/steven) holds a really good insight on how to label in matplotlib. The function pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie wraps matplotlib.pyplot.pie() so we can use some of the techniques from that link.

First we declare a function to covert percentage into whole number. This function is similar to the one given by this [link](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html). I have added round() to the function so that it won't given a false number (Ex. int(889.99) = 899 but we want 900)

```
# Covert percent and total to value
def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(round(pct/100*np.sum(allvals)))
    return "${:.1f}".format(absolute)
```

Now we can plot the pie chart out with label, we can specify the autopct similar to the one from the [link](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html)

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,10))
for ax, col in zip(axes, df_flatten.columns):
    print(col)
    df_flatten[col].plot(kind='pie', autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, df_flatten[col].tolist()), labels=df_flatten.index,  ax=ax, title=col, fontsize=10)
    ax.legend(loc=3)
```

Your labels should now appear.

[image: result]